Connecting of array with duplicate records with prisma
I have a project with prisma for a practice CBT software. on my database i am to recieve random questions for a particular topic and some questions will be duplicate(This is what i want). I connect these questions to my "quiz" object via
 console.log(questions) 
    const quiz = await prisma.quiz.create({
      data: {
        duration,
        score: 0,
        subject: {
          connect: {
            id: subject,
          },
        },
        topic: topic
          ? {
              connect: { id: topic },
            }
          : undefined,
        questions: {
          connect: questions.map((q) => ({ id: q.id })),
        },
      },
      include: {
        questions: true,
      },
    });

And prisma automatically removes the duplicates. How do i make it so that it keeps duplicate questions in the quiz.
